# "Conversion from string " " to type 'Double' is not valid"

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion

I am doing a project in microsoft visual studio 2012 and i am trying to write an application to determine the module average.

The script is the following:

```js
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles confirm.Click
        Dim sum As Double
        sum = CDbl(test.Text) * 50% + CDbl(project.Text) * 30% + CDbl(quiz.Text) * 30%
        Dim modulemark As Double
        modulemark = CDbl(CAmarks.Text) * 50% + CDbl(exam.Text) * 50%

        Dim Grade As String
        If sum < 40 Then
            Grade = "F"
        ElseIf sum >= 40 And modulemark < 65 And modulemark >= 40 Then
            Grade = "C"
        ElseIf sum >= 40 And modulemark < 75 And modulemark >= 65 Then
            Grade = "B"
        Else
            Grade = "A"
        End If
```

The script is intended to calculate the marks and give a grade after clicking a button named "Confirm".

However, when i tried to run the coding it said:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.

can someone see what is wrong? i am new to Visual studio and i appreciate your help.

P.S. edited recent script.

P.S. Thank you for the user "Tim" for the script <s>but for some unknown reason on the line "Double.TryParse(caMarks.Text, caMarks)" there's a blue squiggly that directs to caMarks that says "'Text' is not a member of 'double'". This is literally pulling my hair off! please help!</s>

It looks like the names of the objects conflicted.

Comment: Well - what is wrong is that you're somewhere trying to convert "" to a double. Likely in one of the CDbl(*.text) calls. Debug your code and find out which.

Comment: I debugged and It said the line " sum = CDbl(test.Text) * 50% + CDbl(project.Text) * 30% + CDbl(quiz.Text) * 30%" was wrong. P.S. i tried turning the  "Dim Grade As Integer" section into a "Dim Grade As Double" and it still did not work. any suggestions?

Comment: Have you entered data in all the fields? You can't leave blanks and assume that they would be set to 0.

Comment: Yes. I have still yet to make a verification, however. But i inserted the student name, which is not shown and incomplete and i will do it later, all 4 sections (test, quiz, project, exam) but it still did not work.

Comment: To identify the exact source of error, try creating a separate variable of type Double for each like Dim CMarks as Double: CMarks=CDBL(CMarks.Text) and so on then run your program. This will show you which statement is causing the issue (better use debug mode).

Comment: It gave me an error saying ".Text is not a member of double."

Comment: Try Changing sum = CDbl(test.Text) * 50% + CDbl(project.Text) * 30% + CDbl(quiz.Text) * 30% to "sum = CDbl(Val(test.Text)) * 50% + CDbl(Val(project.Text)) * 30% + CDbl(Val(quiz.Text)) * 30%"

Comment: @sabre - That's almost as bad as the original code.  `CDbl` and `Val` are VB6 holdovers.  `Double.TryParse` is the proper way to go.

Comment: @Tim - CDbl and similiar operators in VB are not legacy.  CDbl is a first class citizen of the VB language.  They are defined in the language spec for VB.Net.  They are not functions, they are called "casting operators"  There is no reason not to use them in VB.Net.

Answer (score 2):

As Idle_Mind said in their answer, [Double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) is the way to go.  This provides a safe way to attempt to convert a value to a double.  If the conversion succeeds, the method returns true, and the resulting double is returned in the out parameter.  If the conversion fails, false is returned and the default value of double (which is 0) is returned.

A simple example:

```
Dim result As Double
Dim score As String = "75"

If Double.TryParse(score, result) Then
   ' result will be a double with the value of 75
Else
   ' The conversion attempt failed, and result will have a value of 0
End If
```

So to apply that to your method (with no validation, though Idle_Mind's answer gives a good approach):

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles confirm.Click

    Dim sum As Double
    Dim modulemark As Double
    Dim testScore As Double
    Dim projectScore As Double
    Dim quizScore As Double
    Dim marks As Double
    Dim examScore As Double

    Double.TryParse(test.Text, testScore)
    Double.TryParse(project.Text, projectScore)
    Double.TryParse(quiz.Text, quizScore)
    Double.TryParse(CAmarks.Text, marks)
    Double.TryParse(exam.Text, examScore)

    sum = (testScore * .5) + (projectScore * .3) + (quizScore * .3)
    modulemark = (marks * .5) + (examScore * .5)

    Dim Grade As String

    If sum < 40 Then
        Grade = "F"
    ElseIf sum >= 40 And modulemark < 65 And modulemark >= 40 Then
        Grade = "C"
    ElseIf sum >= 40 And modulemark < 75 And modulemark >= 65 Then
        Grade = "B"
    Else
        Grade = "A"
    End If
End Sub
```

Explanation of the above code.

First, 6 `Double` variables are declared - this necessary because `Double.TryParse` takes an `out` parameter as the second argument, and that must be declared before its used.  You could use one variable (and reuse it), but for simplicity I chose one for each score.

Once the scores have been parsed (successfully or not) the cumulative, weighted totals are determined.  Note that parentheses were used when applying the weight modifier, to ensure operator precedence doesn't give you a result other than expected.

Hopefully this clarifies things for you.

Comment: Now, on the line "Double.TryParse(CAMarks.Text, CAMarks)" has an error that says:"'Text' is not a member of 'Double'", and only on that line and on CAmarks without any apparent reason. without that there are no problems. once i tried getting that line in, it appears.

Comment: Forgot VB.NET isn't case-sensitive.  Change the double `caMarks` to `marks` and try again.  The reason you got the error was because VB.NET saw `CAMarks` (The textbox) and `caMarks` (the double) as the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're assigning a **letter grade** to this variable...
Change `Dim Grade As Integer`
to `Dim Grade As String`.

Example of Double.TryParse():

```
    Dim testValue As Double, projectValue As Double, quizValue As Double
    If Double.TryParse(test.Text, testValue) Then
        If Double.TryParse(project.Text, projectValue) Then
            If Double.TryParse(quiz.Text, quizValue) Then
                Dim sum As Double
                sum = testValue * 0.5 + projectValue * 0.3 + quizValue * 0.3
                ' ... do something with "sum" ...
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(quiz.Text, "Invalid Quiz Score")
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(project.Text, "Invalid Project Score")
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show(test.Text, "Invalid Test Score")
    End If
```

Comment: You need to move from using all of those CDbl() calls to proper Double.TryParse() calls.  Look it up...

Comment: Additonally, it is unclear if your use of "50%" is correct.  You most likely meant that to be ".5".  The "%" symbol causes that 50 to be treated as an integer, which it already is.  See [Type Characters (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek.aspx).

Comment: Tried. It said: "Overload resolution failed because no accessible tryparse accepts this number of arguments." The script is: "modulemark = Double.TryParse(CAmarks.Text) * 50% + Double.TryParse(exam.Text) * 50%". the dim is already set as double.