# Conversion from string “” to type Long is not valid...If order number is wrong and i tried only numbers not character

Tags: vb.net, casting

How can I fix this error? I am updating this code from VB.06 to vb.net everything is working correctly except this line. And it is happening only when the order number is wrong

[image]

Comment: Error hendelling `Try` and `Catch` blocks are always a good practice

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Conversion from string " " to type 'Double' is not valid"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27416950/conversion-from-string-to-type-double-is-not-valid). Are we not marking questions as duplicates anymore? This question in many forms have been asked numerous times here on SO, we do not need more...

Comment: @Sion.D.P : Not if it can be avoided and handled in a better manner (in this case using [**`Long.TryParse()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2x2b1h(v=vs.110).aspx)). Exceptions are expensive.

Comment: @Codexer : I have to agree that the number of duplicate flags/votes has decreased (apart from questions asking about `NullReferenceException`s). Perhaps people are getting lazier? :)

Comment: @VisualVincent either getting lazier, keep infecting SO with replication and or looking for rep points; not sure... I can't count how many times just this week how many I have seen and the questions don't get closed out, but someone that has been here for awhile posts an answer and then gets accepted, when instead the right thing to do is vote to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string `""` can not be converted to `Long` because it is not a number.

You can use [`TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.int64.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.1#overloads) to convert the string to `Long`. If it can not be parsed then `0` is returned into the variable in the second argument (`orderQty`):

```vb
Dim orderQty As Long
Long.TryParse(txtOrderQty.Text, orderQty)
lblToBeScanned1.Text = (orderQty - lngUPC1).ToString()
```

Comment: @Doll : You can also check the return value of `Long.TryParse()` to determine if parsing was successful or not. If not, you can show a message to the user.

Comment: IMO please help keep SO clean and mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: @Codexer That was my first intention, but I did not find an exact duplicate. And if you look for the exact error message with a search engine, almost only "string to date - conversion" questions are found on SO. (BTW: So far I have probably marked many more questions as a duplicate than I have answered. ;-) )

Comment: @MatSnow Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how you like to handle the error.
you can wrap the line with

```
 if txtOrderQty.text <> "" then

 end if
```

and let the code to continue.

or you can issue a warning message before processing further.

Comment: What if the user doesn't enter a number character into the textbox? "A" cannot be converted to long either. Use TryParse as suggested.

Comment: I tried this way and tested the code and it did work



if txtOrderQty.text <> "" then
Dim orderQty As Long

Long.TryParse(txtOrderQty.Text, orderQty)
lblToBeScanned1.Text = (orderQty - lngUPC1).ToString()

 end if

Answer (score 0):

if txtOrderQty.text  <>  ""   then

Dim orderQty As Long

Long.TryParse(txtOrderQty.Text, orderQty)

lblToBeScanned1.Text = (orderQty - lngUPC1).ToString()

end if