# system.invalidcastexception 'conversion from string to type 'double' is not valid.' vb.net

Tags: vb.net

system.invalidcastexception 'conversion from string to type 'double' is not valid.

```vb
    ' vb.net
    receiptDetails = lstReceipt.SelectedItem
    Dim newTotalAmount As Double = CDbl(receiptDetails.Remove(0, 94))

    lstReceipt.Items.RemoveAt(lstReceipt.SelectedIndex)
    totalAmount -= newTotalAmount

    txtTotal.Text = totalAmount.ToString("GH₵###,###.00")
    txtDiscount.Text = discountAmount.ToString("GH₵###,###.00")
    txtTaxableAmount.Text = TaxableAmount.ToString("GH₵###,###.00")
    txtVat.Text = taxAmount.ToString("GH₵###,###.00")
    txtPayableAmount.Text = payableAmount.ToString("GH₵###,###.00")

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Conversion from string " " to type 'Double' is not valid"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27416950/conversion-from-string-to-type-double-is-not-valid)

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, the code is failing at:

```vb
Dim newTotalAmount As Double = CDbl(receiptDetails.Remove(0, 94))
```

I suggest using `TryParse` instead of `CDbl` to verify that the value can be converted to a Double. If the result of `TryParse` is `False`, then display the value that attempted to be converted:

```vb
Dim massagedValue As String = receiptDetails.Remove(0, 94)
Dim newTotalAmount As Double
If (Double.TryParse(massagedValue, newTotalAmount)) Then
    ' continue business logic ...
Else
    MessageBox.Show($"The following value is not a valid double: {massagedValue}", "Invalid Double", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End If
```

Now when you get the user-friendly error message you can determine why the value is not able to be converted to a double.

My best guess is that you are not removing enough or are removing too much characters from the `receiptDetails` variable.